# Error: cannot convert from 'long' to 'int &'

Tags: c++, operators

my function `get_num` returns a variable of `long int`.

I want to write the next operator:

```
long int& operator [] (long int i) {
    long int a = get_num(i);
    int& b = a;
    return b;
}
```

but I got the next error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'long' to 'int &'
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'long &'
```

how can I fix it without changing the function of `get_num`?

any help appreciated!

---

I have a class:

```
class B {
   B* next;
   long int nom;
   long int denom;
  public:
   long int get_nom() {return nom; }
   long int get_denom() {return denom; }
};

class List {
  B* head;
public:
 long int& operator [] (long int desired_denom) {
      // here I search the node that containts the denom that is equal to desired_denom
      // and insert it to tmp (it's a pointer to B).
      long int a1 = tmp->get_nom()
      long int& a2 = a1;
      return a2;
    }
};
```

now in the `main`, I want to do:

```
int main() {
    A a; // assume that it creates the list of B and put values in each node (each B)
    // here I want to do:
    a[2] = 3; // it should search the node that his denom is equal to 2, and puts 3 instead of his nom
    return 0;
}
```

for example:

if my list is:

```
(nom=5, denom=6)->(nom=1,denom=8)->(nom=4, denom=2)->NULL
```

the line `a[2]=3` searches the node that his denom is 2 (it's the third node) and set his nom to 3.

so after this line, my list will be:

```
(nom=5, denom=6)->(nom=1,denom=8)->(nom=3, denom=2)->NULL
```

Comment: Why are you returning a reference to an integer, in first place? Also, returning a reference to a local automatic variable is UB.

Comment: @H2CO3 Return a reference is perfectly normal for `operator[]`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, but not a reference to a _local_ variable.

Comment: I have to return the parameter of `get_num(I)`. so how can I do that please?

Comment: @AlonShmiel `long &operator [] (long &i) { return i; }`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That's obviously stupid. I would never suggest otherwise.

Comment: Please show `get_num()`. If `get_num()` returns by value, then you cannot hope to return a reference. Ask yourself what you would be referring to.

Comment: Without changing the code? Use `long val = object[0];` instead of `int val = object[0]`.

Comment: I would really appreciate if someone will give an example what could be a practical usage of such operator.. Just cannot image design where it can be used.

Comment: @evilruff `object[x] = value` assigns `value` to the element at `x`. If you did not return a reference to the element or an intermediate you could not assign a value to it.

Comment: @evilruff I expect you are familiar with this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at

Comment: Thats clear, I am wondering that there is get_num function which obviously returns a *copy* of long int.. and then whats the sense to return a reference to something which is already copy...

Comment: If get_num would return a reference OK.. I can see a point, but then an operator should just return a get_num value as mentioned in answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in your code there isn't a way to modify the nodes the way you want to. `get_nom` will have to be changed to return a reference before it can behave the way you would like. Right now you can only make copy of the values in each node of the linked list.

Assuming tmp is set correctly you can return the reference returned by `get_nom`

```
long int& operator [] (long int i) {
    //Get tmp here probably by list traversal
    return tmp->get_nom(i);
}
```

And then the implementation of `get_nom`. It is important to note that `nom` must be a value with a lifespan long enough to be of use as explained below. Returning `nom` which is private to the class and therefor will not fall out of scope when the function returns should work.

```
long int& get_nom() {return nom; }
```

`get_nom` must return `long int&` for this to work. There is an important difference between returning `long int` and `long int&`. When the return type is `long int` a copy of the value you are returning is made and passed to the caller. When you return `long int&` or in other words return a long int by reference, the reference points to the location in memory where the value is stored. This reference allows you to change the value of a long int while it is still stored in the middle of an array or whatever data type you are using.

Another important side effect of this is that if you return a reference to a local variable, when the variable falls out of scope, the value will no longer exist in memory. I haven't actually tried compiling and running this so I'm not sure if the compiler will get mad or what exactly the result will be, but I know it won't be good:

```
long int& operator [] (long int i) {
    long int a = i + 5; //arbitrary change
    return a;
}
```

In this case you are returning a reference to the location of `a`, but because a falls out of scope after the function finishes executing, the reference no longer points to anything at all. The variable you are returning a reference to must still exist after the function exits.

Comment: I have: p = "1/2x", and I'm trying to do: p[1] = 3 (the output should be: "3/2x". the operator returns the first long int of p[1] (the long int of '1'), but it doesn't put '3' instead of the '1'. how can I fix it please?

Comment: Does get_num return `long int` or `long int&`? There is an important difference between the two. I'll elaborate in my answer.

Comment: get_num returns `long int` and in my operator I wrote: long int nom = getnom(i); long int& r_nom = nom; return r_nom;

Comment: @AlonShmiel I don't know why you are making us guess what `get_num` is. Why won't you show its declaration?

Comment: you,re right :) I have a list of nodes. each node contains nom,denom (long int). the function getnom, get a denom, searches it in the list and return the nom that his node contains the desired denom..

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I improved my question with more details.

Comment: @Danny, thank you very much for your comment.. Can you show me please the changes that I have to do in order to make this operator works? I tried: long int& get_nom() {return nom; } (but I got an error).

Comment: @AlonShmiel I updated my answer. Hopefully that helps. If that doesn't work still give me some specifics on the error that is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

The compile error is for this line

```
int& b = a;
^^^^
```

It should be

```
long int& b = a;
^^^^^^^^
```

And, as friends have said in the comments, returning a reference to a local variable leads to a undefined-behavior because that referenced variable will be destroyed after exiting the function.

Blindly asnwering, you might need return a reference to the `get_num`, if `get_num` is returning a reference correctly.

```
return get_num(i);
```